# Is originating_app_id parameter ready for production code?

Tags: google-drive-api

The Drive activity events from Google Admin Reports API query (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/reports_v1/admin/reports_v1/reports.activities.list?userKey=all&applicationName=drive&maxResults=50&_h=2&) now seem to include an 'originating_app_id' parameter whose value is set to the project ID of the APP that's responsible for causing the corresponding events.

This new parameter is extremely useful. For instance, one can now easily filter out events generated by an APP itself (ignoring self-events) using this parameter. If not for this parameter, one needs to perform round about ways to filter out self-generated events (*using appProperties for instance*)

While I'm glad that this new parameter has come into existence, I would like to know if it is still experimental or can be used in production code as-is.

Could someone please confirm?

The reason I need confirmation is because the parameter (*originating_app_id*) didn't appear in the drive events until 12-Jun-2017 and I see it in the drive events beyond 19-Jun-2017. So, the change seems pretty recent and the documentation (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/drive-event-names?authuser=1) too is not updated yet.

So, a confirmation would help me use this new parameter confidently in the production code.

Comment: AFAIK,for features not currently supported,a good rule of thumb is, "If it's not documented, it's still not available."

Comment: Many a times we may be able to make use of undocumented features if agreed upon with the vendors. Hoping to see some kind of confirmation here.

Answer (score 1):

You can decode the originating_app_id by entering in the appID field [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/apps/get).

From this, I was able to understand that app ID '947318989803' corresponds to Google Drive File Stream, and that 0 corresponds to a download originating from the web. Has anyone ever encountered app ID codes like 645529619299? I'm getting a "App not found: 645529619299" error from the API referenced above.